# Stack Snippets Returning Service Unavailable

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

Trying to run some [Stack Snippets](http://stacksnippets.net/) and I'm getting:

> Service Unavailable
>
> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

Comment: Aware and investigating now. Sorry for slow response on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. A misconfiguration on our side meant that the Stack Snippets app was deployed but not started. We have started the app back up and http://stacksnippets.net is now responding normally.

Comment: Not the kind of answer that is ever welcome at SO.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5_Whys

Comment: I don't yet have the root cause and I'd rather share that we fixed it than hold off for what could be a week or more to reply at all. When critiquing my answer, ask yourself which is more important: a definitive answer indicating that the problem is solved, or radio silence until I can perfectly describe exactly what happened?

Comment: Nothing ever wrong with a comment.

Comment: @Haney Seems like this is happening again.

Comment: Not working for me either ... in Norway

Comment: I posted my tracert here if it can be to any help: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343548/stack-snippets-not-working