# Stack snippets not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

I'm sure you've seen it though the Stack snippets render `Service Unavailable`

Also, is this the proper place to post an issue like this?

Here is my tracert if it can help

```
Tracing route to stacksnippets.net [198.252.206.24]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  local/outgoing isp
  2    32 ms    37 ms    39 ms  local/outgoing isp
  3    30 ms    29 ms    22 ms  local/outgoing isp
  4    59 ms    56 ms    58 ms  local/outgoing isp
  5    70 ms    80 ms    75 ms  ae10-0.prg-peer2.osl.no.ip.tdc.net [80.232.88.44]
  6    75 ms    76 ms    77 ms  ae1-0.kst-peer1.sto.se.ip.tdc.net [62.95.54.122]
  7    90 ms    97 ms    98 ms  10gigabitethernet1-2.core1.sto1.he.net [194.68.123.187]
  8    53 ms    55 ms    93 ms  10ge12-6.core1.ams1.he.net [72.52.92.45]
  9   101 ms   142 ms   100 ms  100ge9-1.core1.lon2.he.net [72.52.92.213]
 10   172 ms   168 ms   171 ms  100ge1-1.core1.nyc4.he.net [72.52.92.166]
 11   171 ms   174 ms   172 ms  10ge4-1.core1.nyc5.he.net [184.105.213.218]
 12   185 ms   159 ms   166 ms  lightower-fiber-networks.10gigabitethernet3-2.core1.nyc5.he.net [216.66.50.106]
 13   118 ms   115 ms   177 ms  ae12-nycmnyzrj91.lightower.net [64.72.64.110]
 14   147 ms   150 ms   148 ms  ae14-nwrknjmdj91.lightower.net [104.207.214.76]
 15   153 ms   154 ms   167 ms  ae3-jrcynj67j41.lightower.net [104.207.214.180]
 16   155 ms   162 ms   160 ms  38.140.97.250
 17   161 ms   166 ms   166 ms  stackoverflow.com [198.252.206.24]
```

Comment: Maybe not a dupe: but is it not working *again* ...

Comment: I can't repro. It works for me... anything special you're doing?

Comment: I'm on Chrome (and IE11) and getting this issue now ... sitting in Norway

Comment: I'm on Chrome as well and also in Western Europe so our network paths are kind of identical

Comment: It is on an existing snippet? Does [this one work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290847/158100) for you?

Comment: I've tested both my own and others, neither works

Comment: So if you try to hit [http://stacksnippets.net/](http://stacksnippets.net/) you get that 503?

Comment: @rene Yes, I do get 503

Comment: That is strange, you must be hitting a bad server then behind the load balancer

Comment: [here](https://gist.github.com/rschrieken/1aa747e53bab3cf0966b71ecb6ddeaac) is my tracert but I expect yours will be the same from hop 6 onward.

Comment: @rene Updated my question with my tracert

Comment: Hmm, your traffic goes through the AMS-IX as well ... except you have a few hops extra. This needs a dev or SRE to look into.

Comment: The app pool for stack snippets was done on one of the web servers, it has been restarted, so should work now.

Comment: @Oded Yepp, it does, thanks